# For loop stops if Element is not present in JArray - Java

Tags: java, json

I have this bit of code that is handling a JSON string; it has two objects (one called `Code` and the other called `Result`)

`Result` is an array - I know I have 62 elements in this array, and I can prove it by printing the length of the array to the console.

Here's an example of two elements from the Result array, shown here separately for simplicity:

> Example 1 -
>   {"Name":"AName","ID":1,"Question":"Ready?","QuestionAnswered":"1"}
>
> Example 2 - {"Name":"AName","ID":1,"Question":"Ready?"}

The issue is that I need to get the values of QuestionAnswered if they are present - but when they are not present (like in Example 2), my for loop stops and doesn't continue through the remainder of the array...

```
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("Result");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Details answer = new Details ();
                    answer.setAnswer(object.getString("QuestionAnswered"));
                    answer.setAnswerID(object.getInt("ID"));
                    createDB.addToWorksheetAnswers(answer);
                    }
                }
```

I tried adding `if (object.getString("Answer") != null)` but it didn't make any difference.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    if (object.getString("QuestionAnswered") != null) {
                      Details answer = new Details ();
                      answer.setAnswer(object.getString("QuestionAnswered"));
                      answer.setAnswerID(object.getInt("ID"));
                      createDB.addToWorksheetAnswers(answer);
                     }
                    }
                }
```

Why is the for loop stopping? Should I do this differently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.getString("Answer")`? You said that it is `"QuestionAnswered"`... On which line does the for loop stop? Is it on `addToWorksheetAnswers`? What does this method do? Connecting to database? Is it blocking?

Comment: Why `if(object.getString("Answer"))` instead of `"QuestionAnswered"`?

Comment: Sorry, typo - my point still stands though.@JaroslawPawlak, with the if statement in the code, it stops at that line but doesn't continue with the loop even though there are more values remaining

Comment: (which is correct btw - because the if evaluates to false, so the code within the if statement is not executed. The issue is that the for loop then doesn't proceed to run through any more of the array)

Comment: There is a difference between program execution stopping due to blocking calls (e.g. awaiting user input) and for loop just not iterating over the remainder of the array. Which one is it? Why don't you run this code with debugger (or just add `System.out.println` every second line) and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used this library personally, however, according to the documentation it looks like that `NullPointerException` is thrown if no mapping exists for the provided key (since the method is a shortcut for the `getJsonString(name).getString()`), check out the following link : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonString-java.lang.String-.

It looks like that you should be able to use the null check by using the `getJsonString(name)` method instead, and if the check passes then grab the `toString()` value of the result.

If you use the Android's JSON library then it also seems to throw an exception if mapping does not exist :
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String) . In this case you may use `has(name)` to identify if mapping exists prior to trying to retrieve it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this is not the library OP is using. Just have a look at `JsonObject` vs `JSONObject`.

Comment: However, the exception throwing behavior seems to be true also for the Android's JSON library : https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Yes, I thouht about an unlogged `Exception` already, but I can't tell it for sure unless I know the JSON library OP is using.

Comment: Yes! You are a life saver @RubenDilanyan. It was the second idea, for Android. Using has(name) works a dream. Many thanks